# Oracle trigger for allowing DML on view

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view, triggers

I have View in Oracle DB:

```
  CREATE VIEW view1
AS SELECT
  id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  c1>1100 AND c1<2000
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

And table `table1` with columns id, c1, ... c9.
Now i want make trigger(s) on this view for allowing DML operations with data thas is not in this view. But i dont know whitch columns will be updated, whitch rows deleted or inserted. For example

```
UPDATE view1 SET c1=3000 WHERE c1=1500;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO view1 VALUES(3500, .......);
```

Someone has an idea?

Edit: I know, that doesn't make sense, but this is part of my project and this part will show how to bypass the constraint of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution for delete:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DML_VIEW_DELETE
    INSTEAD OF DELETE ON myview
BEGIN
    DELETE table
    WHERE id = :old.id;
END;
```

And similar for update and insert only with `:new` instead of `:old` and with `null` in columns which aren't in the view

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are attempting to insert / update via a view, and at the same time bypass the constraint that the view imposes - this doesn't seem to make much sense. Either way, I don't believe you'll need to use another workaround like a trigger here.

In general, since your view utilizes only one table, you can update through the view without triggers et al, provided that you remain within the `CHECK OPTION` range for `c1 (i.e. between 1100 and 2000)`:

```
INSERT INTO view1(c1, ...) 
VALUES (1101, );

UPDATE view1 
SET c1 = 1102 
WHERE id = 1;
```

But not this:

```
UPDATE view1 
SET c1 = 23 
WHERE id = 1;

-- ORA-01402: view WITH CHECK OPTION where-clause violation
```

However, if you want to bypass the constraint, you could :

- Insert / Update to the table directly (i.e. `update table1 set c1 = 23 where ...`)
- Create another view without the `WHERE` filter and `CHECK CONSTRAINT` and then update through this (but again, why?)

I've added a [SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8c4d/1) showing the above approaches

Comment: I know, that doesn't make sense at all, but this is part of my project to show how to bypass the constraint of view and i cant figure out, how to make it. I dont know how to start or what make first...